# Export HTML as PDF in JQuery for Persian

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, html2pdf, persian

I used some free jquery libraries like jsPDF and html2pdf to export html as PDF in jquery. But non of them work properly for Persian language. How to export/convert html to PDF for Persian with Persian fonts in jquery or javascript?

please help me!

Answer (score 1):

You can use DocRaptor. It works for Persian and other utf-8 languages. but it's not free. In free version of library, advertising bar will be added to exporting PDF.

Comment: Actually i want a free library without extra elements in PDF.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a simple page with your report as html, and use Microsoft Print to PDF-se (Ctrl+P) to print to PDF-se and save locally

Answer (score 0):

jsPDF can only render simple HTML to PDF

See below image, There is a  tag which is not displaying properly in PDF view:
[image]

You need to use [iTextSharp](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp) in order to generate PDF from server side. it will also support Persian font.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **[html2pdf](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js)** library for properly export Persian/Arabic characters.